# Ruby substring explanation needed

Tags: ruby, string, substring

I have two strings `str1 = 'abbab'` and `str2 = 'ba'`. If I do

```
str1.include? str2
```

I get `true`. When I do

```
str2.include? str1
```

why do I get `false`?

How should I find if `str2` is a substring of `str1` when it is at position `2`, i.e. `str1[2..3] == str2`?

Comment: `x.include? y` means *does **x** include **y**?*. Therefore, if **y** is substring of **x**, `x.include? y` will return `true`. `y.include? x` will return `false`, unless **x** is a substring of **y** too, aka `x == y`. Not sure where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @YuHao, it's more like `1 <= 2` is `true`, while `2 <= 1` is `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What is a substring?**

> A substring of a string is another string that occurs ***"in"***.

going by above definition:

`'ba'` occurs in `'abbab'`, therefore `'ba'` is a substring of `'abbab'`.

Now looking other way round:

Does `'abbab'` occur inside `'ba'`? No. So `'abbab'` is not a substring of `'ba'`.

> How should I find if `str2` is a substring of `str1`?

By doing:

```
str1.include? str2 #true
```

> How can I find `str1` is a substring of `str2`?

```
str2.include? str1 #false
# since its not, you are getting false.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering shivam, but why is str2 not a substing of str1,
when str2 i.e 'ba' is there in str1 i.e 'abbab' on position 2-3.?

Comment: because "A substring of a string is another string that occurs *"in"*". Explaining it with analogy - "India is in Asia? => true" , "Asia is in India? => false"

Comment: thanks got it. I was thinking a part of substring should also return true as abbab does have ba but as ba also occurs in abbab it should return true both ways.

Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Rails / ActiveSupport provides an [`in?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-in-3F) method: `str2.in? str1 #=> true`

Answer (score 1):

[`Read the documentation carefully`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/include%3F):

```
include? other_str → true or false
```

> Returns `true` if str contains the given string or character.

Example:

```
=> "foobar".include? "bar"
#> true
=> "bar".include? "foobar"     
#> false
```